# array_intersect returns Severity: 4096 Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass, array-intersect

I got two arrays both have multiple values with std Class objects, I want to use 'array_intersect' but it shows "Severity: 4096  Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Controller Code:

```
    $AlreadyInsertedList = $this->bill->GetBillsbyDate($Givendate); //array1
    $NotInserted = $this->admin->GetACustomersbyArea($areaid);       //array2
    $finallist = NULL;        //finalarray
    $finallist = array_intersect($AlreadyInsertedList,$allcustomersbyarea); //Line number 88 
    //$array = json_decode(json_encode($finallist)); //already tried not working
```

Although it is giving the required results but with a lot of errors, I'm attaching a screen shot of it, do have a look at the scoll bar (a long length of errors)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code returns the desired results..

```
function ary_diff( $ary_1, $ary_2 ) {   // compare the value of 2 array   // get differences that in ary_1 but not in ary_2   // get difference that in ary_2 but not in ary_1   // return the unique difference between value of 2 array   $diff = array();

  // get differences that in ary_1 but not in ary_2   foreach ( $ary_1 as $v1 ) {
    $flag = 0;
    foreach ( $ary_2 as $v2 ) {
      $flag |= ( $v1 == $v2 );
      if ( $flag ) break;
    }
    if ( !$flag ) array_push( $diff, $v1 );   }

  // get difference that in ary_2 but not in ary_1   foreach ( $ary_2 as $v2 ) {
    $flag = 0;
    foreach ( $ary_1 as $v1 ) {
      $flag |= ( $v1 == $v2 );
      if ( $flag ) break;
    }
    if ( !$flag && !in_array( $v2, $diff ) ) array_push( $diff, $v2 );   }

  return $diff; }
```

Comment: If this code worked for you then you can accept your own answer, so please do that so the question can be closed.